# Add checkbox to Magento checkout?

Tags: magento

I've been searching, trying, and failing alot here. What I want is to add a checkbox, on the Shipping page of Onepage checkout, the standard magento checkout.

I want to create a checkbox so that customers can check it if they want their products to be placed on their address without a signature.

I've been messing around with some old "Accept Terms" checkboxes, but with no luck.

I'm hoping that somebody might have had to make the same kind of customization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is save the preference in the `checkout/session` via an observer. First, add the checkbox to the shipping section and give it the property of `name=shipping[no_signature]`. Then, create a new module and hook into the event `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping` and then use this code:

```
public function controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping($observer)
{
    $params = (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()) ? Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams() : array();
    if (isset($params['shipping']['no_signature']) && $params['shipping']['no_signature']) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoSignature(true);
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoSignature(false);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Then, when the order is about to be placed, hook into the event `sales_order_place_before` you can add a comment to the order like this:

```
public function sales_order_place_before($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNoSignature()) {
        $order->setCustomerNote('No signature required.');
    } else {
        $order->setCustomerNote(null);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

When you go to Sales > Orders, you should see a comment on the order regarding if the customer requires a signature or not. This is under the assumption that no other module or custom code is injecting anything into the `customer_note` field on the order object.